# common_schema extract_json_value ans special chars

Tags: mysql, json, special-characters

I'm using extract_json_value from common_schema (http://common-schema.googlecode.com/) to json_decode a field in my MySQL database.
It works pretty well...exept for accents.

```
SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(value,'prenom') as prenom
FROM metadata where idmetadata = 720871;
```

returns: Aur\u00e9lien

field value in database is: {"prenom":"Aur\u00e9lien","classe":"CP"}

Any idea on how i can get "Aurélien" and not "Aur\u00e9lien" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't seem to be with common schema, but with your charset. Make sure

1. your MySQL database (and all tables) collation is `utf8-general-ci`
2. Your web forms include the HTML attribute `accept-charset="UTF-8"`
3. Your html pages include `<meta charset="utf-8">`
4. If using gettext for translation, set the codeset in PHP: `bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');`